# The import org.apache.commons.dbcp2 cannot be resolved in a maven project using apache camel

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipse, maven, apache-camel

I am trying to connect to a postgreSQL database using apache camel in eclipse IDE however I am getting this error:
The import org.apache.commons.dbcp2 cannot be resolved

when importing: import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource;

these are the dependencies in the pom:

```
    <dependencies>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
    <!-- use the same version as your Camel core version -->
</dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
   
</dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-http-common</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
```

I don t know what to do and appreciate any help!!

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by adding the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```